# Social.framework don't work on device

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharing

I want make button for share on Facebook with the social.framework. I make this:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import <Social/Social.h>

    @interface SocialSharingViewController : UIViewController

    - (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender;

    @end
```

Then I add in m. File:

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];        
    }
}
```

It's work perfect in emulator but when I test this on my iPhone 5 device it's doesn't work. When I click on the button postToFacebook nothing happens.

Pleas help me

Answer (score 2):

The possible error is that your iphone 5 is not configured any fb account. `[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]` will return NO in this case

As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the SLComposeViewController, isAvailableForServiceType "returns a Boolean value indicating whether the service is accessible and at least one account is set up... For the account to be available, the user must be logged into the social service in the device settings."

*NOTE: Whenever you add a if condition, use else condition too. #codingstandard*